# Manually track changes in Entity DbContext and save changes in to the another DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I present an 'Update' page in my ASP.NET MVC project that enables 'Admin' to update some DbSets with information comes from an Excel file. If the entity exist in the database, I update values; in this case, there is a column mapping algorithm which only updates properties that are mapped with columns from DataTable. If not, I add a new entity to the context.

Before calling SaveChanges() methods, I would like to track changes, such as whether the entry is added or updated, and save them to another DbSet, called Changes. For the 'Updated' scenario, I would like to know which properties are updated including old/new values information.

```
foreach (var item in db.Items)
{
    var entry = db.Entry(item);
    switch (entry.State)
    {
        case EntityState.Added:
            Debug.Print("Item added: " + item.Name);
            break;
        case EntityState.Modified:
            Debug.Print("Item updated: " + item.Name);
            Debug.Print("Original: " + entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames);
            Debug.Print("Current: " + entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames);
            break;
        case EntityState.Unchanged:
            Debug.Print("No changes detected: " + item.Name);
            break;
    }
}
```

'Update' operation is where I'm stuck. 'entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames' returns an array (                                  System.Data.Entity.Internal.ReadOnlySet`1[System.String]) but I am not sure how to get old and new values.

Sorry if this question is a stupid one. Could you give me some advice how to do it or offer another approach?

Comment: You can use db.AsNoTracking() to get the original values. Where db is a DbContext.

Comment: I've searched google DbContext AsNoTracking but couldn't find useful regarding to my question. Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found some solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx). If there is better approach, please do not hesitate to contribute.